# ImportError: cannot import Oscpy libraries in my Android app

Tags: python, kivy, osc

I am developing an application for android using python / kivy / buildozer.

when I import oscpy libraries, the application does not start.

```
from oscpy.server import OSCThreadServer
from oscpy.client import OSCClient
```

when I comment on these lines, the application is normally generated in the buildozer.

does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How would the commenting look like that causes the application to generate normally?

Comment: i am using virtual machine. i installed oscpy on virtual machine. `python3 -m pip install oscpy`, but that didn't solve. if i do `buildozer -v android debug deploy run` with these line commented (with `#` before), the apk woks fine on mobile. so, if i discomment these line (importing these libraries), the apk just dont start, without error message.

Comment: i had the following result with logcat: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oscpy'**. i think i have to install **oscpy** on buildozer. so, i don't know how to do that.

Comment: i dowloaded oscpy from [https://pypi.org/project/oscpy/] and copy **oscpy** folder to my project folder. Solved.